# Laravel5.2にてTinyMCE導入後、artisanが使えなくなってしまいます。

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

### 環境

Vagrant + VirtualBox + CentOS6.7
Laravel5.2

### 概要

Laravel5.2にて「TinyMCE」を導入後、artisanを実行するとエラーが発生してしまいます。
TinyMCE導入時に他に何かしなくてはいけないことがあるのでは…？と考えていますが解決方法がわかりません。よろしくお願いします。

### TinyMCE導入

https://github.com/ktquez/laravel-tinymce

こちらを参照して下記を実行しました。

```
$ composer require ktquez/laravel-tinymce
```

config/app.phpに下記を追加

```
'providers' => [
・・・
Ktquez\Tinymce\TinymceServiceProvider::class,
・・・
```

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish --force
```

### エラー

```
$ php artisan
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in /パス/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 62 and defined in /パス/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php on line 103

Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in /パス/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 62 and defined in /パス/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php on line 103
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

laravel-tinymceのsrc/config/tinymce.phpというファイルに以下の記述があるのですが・・・

```
return [
    'cdn' => url('vendor/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js'),
    ...
];
```

configファイルが読み込まれる時点では `url()` ヘルパを使うことができません。

[Using url helper in config files breaks Artisan · Issue #7671 · laravel/framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7671)

この件は過去にlaravel-tinymceリポジトリでも指摘されている（[Issue #2](https://github.com/ktquez/laravel-tinymce/issues/2)）のですが、[今年3月のコミット](https://github.com/ktquez/laravel-tinymce/commit/ec6e4b176f463f7557625a6eda9c09ae1b3c4802)で修正前の記述に戻ってしまったようです。

とりあえずの策としては、デグレ前のコミットを参照するとかどうでしょうか。前述のコミットでの改良点（TinyMCEの更新、configの追加）は得られませんが。この場合以下のコマンドでパッケージのバージョンを切り替えることができます。

```
$ composer require ktquez/laravel-tinymce dev-master#ef652008
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。また、Issueで指摘していただいたようでありがとうございます。
ひとまず旧バージョンを使用して改善されるのを待ちたいと思います。